# When click on the link page is showing up but js is not loading, JS is loading after I refresh the page(Ruby on Rails application)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, codemirror

When I am clicking on the erb link in rails frontend all the content is loading but the js is not loading, JS is loading when I refresh the page. I have tested this clearing the cache also but still getting the same error.

[Before page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/945SG.png)
[After page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGUE5.jpg)

Comment: Can you maybe share some code? Difficult to debug from the two screenshots. But I'd assume it has something to do with turbolinks.

Comment: This code is for clicking the link <%= link_to post_path(post), method: :delete, class: "ml-auto delete-post-icon mx-0 my-auto" do %>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <% end %> When we click on the above link show page is showing without the JS loading.

Comment: Thanks for the hint I just changed my Turbolinks code from $(document).ready(function(){
});  to $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
}); and its working

Comment: Glad I could help :D